Is there a way to make a grayscale filter apply to the rest of the page when hovering over an element?
I am very new to this and am trying to customize my profile on a website that supports html/css coding. I have figured out how to grayscale my images until hover, but I am wondering if there is a way to greyscale the rest of the page on hover so the image is the only colored element.
Everything I have tried has been quite literally just throwing stuff at the wall and seeing if it sticks as I do not know where to even start with something like this, so I don't believe adding my failed attempts will be of any assistance. Below is my current coding for the images, they all fall under the same css ID.
.img{
  filter: Grayscale(100%);
}

.img:hover {
  transform: scale(X);
  filter: drop-shadow(Xpx Xpx  #xxx) !important;
  filter: Grayscale(0%);
}

My apologies if this post does not supply enough information, English is not my first language and I admittedly have no idea what I am doing.

Can you provide a minimal reproducible example so contributors can help you with your problem? Also please read how do I ask a good question. You'll get better answers if you follow this guidance.

You can achieve something like this by making use of the CSS :has()-selector. Checking the body if it currently has an img that is being hovered. If yes apply the following CSS to all (*) elements that are not an img that is currently being hovered.
edit: you can exchange img in this selector with any other selector/class, just make sure to replace both.
edit2: as @CBroe mentioned in the comments, you might want to change the selector to body:has(img:hover) *:not(:hover) (removing the second img selector to make it work when you desired elements are nested.


body:has(img:hover) *:not(:hover) {
  filter: grayscale(1);
}
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1/300"/><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/11/300"/><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/21/300"/><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/31/300"/><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/41/300"/><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/51/300"/><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/61/300"/><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/71/300"/><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/81/300"/><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/91/300"/><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/101/300"/>




This won't work any more, as soon as an image is nested into any other element.

@CBroe you're right. A change to the selector can make it work again though. Since only one element is hovered, the selector can also look like this. Works nested. body:has(img:hover) *:not(:hover)

Removing the second img selector worked! Thank you very much ♡

Should be noted that the parent elements themselves won't be filtered either. So if they have a background-color/image, it won't be filtered, and if they have a non gray color, their textNodes won't be filtered either. (and you should probably remove the second img from the last selector even in the snippet).

@Kaiido I did realize that after applying the code but I actually quite like the effect that it gives. Thank you for explaining more, I will be noting this down for future endeavors!
